# How to properly use tor-privoxy Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, linux, web-scraping, mechanize, tor

I am using tor-privoxy Ruby gem. According to this page: https://github.com/pirj/tor-privoxy
I installed "tor" and "privoxy" packages on my Arch Linux installation. I issued commands:

```
sudo systemctl start privoxy.service
sudo systemctl start tor.service
```

Status of the services, by "systemctl status privoxy.service" and "systemctl status tor.service":

```
● tor.service - Anonymizing Overlay Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-06-26 16:27:44 CEST; 1 weeks 5 days ago
 Main PID: 454 (tor)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service
           └─454 /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc

Jul 08 16:28:28 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Application request when we haven't used client functionality late...gain.
Jul 08 16:28:40 bridgelinux Tor[454]: We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
Jul 08 16:28:41 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functiona...king.
Jul 08 17:20:05 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Socks version 65 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Jul 08 17:20:05 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Jul 08 18:01:25 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Socks version 65 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Jul 08 18:01:25 bridgelinux Tor[454]: Fetching socks handshake failed. Closing.
Jul 08 18:10:04 bridgelinux systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing Overlay Network.
Jul 08 18:10:13 bridgelinux systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing Overlay Network.
Jul 08 18:14:34 bridgelinux systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing Overlay Network.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and

```
● privoxy.service - Privoxy Web Proxy With Advanced Filtering Capabilities
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/privoxy.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2014-07-08 16:09:16 CEST; 2h 8min ago
  Process: 8554 ExecStart=/usr/bin/privoxy --pidfile /run/privoxy.pid --user privoxy.privoxy /etc/privoxy/config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8555 (privoxy)
   CGroup: /system.slice/privoxy.service
           └─8555 /usr/bin/privoxy --pidfile /run/privoxy.pid --user privoxy.privoxy /etc/privoxy/config

Jul 08 16:09:16 bridgelinux systemd[1]: Started Privoxy Web Proxy With Advanced Filtering Capabilities.
Jul 08 18:17:55 bridgelinux systemd[1]: Started Privoxy Web Proxy With Advanced Filtering Capabilities.
```

My Ruby script looks like:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'tor-privoxy'
require 'net/telnet'

def tor
  privoxy_agent ||= TorPrivoxy::Agent.new '127.0.0.1', '', {8118 => 9050} do |agent|
  sleep 20
   puts "New IP is #{agent.ip}"
  end
  return privoxy_agent
end

def switch_endpoint
  localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "localhost", "Port" => "9050", "Timeout" => 10, "Prompt" => /250 OK\n/)
  localhost.cmd('AUTHENTICATE ""') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor" if c != "250 OK\n" }
  localhost.cmd('signal NEWNYM') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot switch Tor to new route" if c != "250 OK\n" }
  localhost.close
end    

agent=tor
```

It shows that my IP adress remained the original one. When I try to call "switch_endpoint" method, I get an error: "ArgumentError: uncaught throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor"

However when I issue this command at bash prompt:

```
torify wget -qO- https://check.torproject.org/ | grep -i congratulations
```

I get no error, and it shows that I was able to connect to Tor network.

What can I do to make Tor-Privoxy work with Ruby and Mechanize?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, you can see in the logs that your authenticate command was refused by tor :

> Socks version 65 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)

I managed to send telnet command to Tor using [Socksify](https://github.com/astro/socksify-ruby) instead of tor-privoxy. You don't need privoxy anymore if you use socksify.

Here is a working example to dynamically swich Tor circuit :

First start Tor specifying password, control port and socks port:

```
tor --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort 9050 --SocksPort 50001
```

Then you can try this in ruby :

```
require 'net/telnet'
require 'socksify'
require 'mechanize'

original_ip = Mechanize.new.get("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com").content
puts "original IP is : #{original_ip}"

# socksify will forward traffic to Tor so you dont need to set a proxy for Mechanize from there
TCPSocket::socks_server = "127.0.0.1"
TCPSocket::socks_port = "50001"
tor_port = 9050

2.times do
  #Switch IP
  localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "localhost", "Port" => "#{tor_port}", "Timeout" => 10, "Prompt" => /250 OK\n/)
  localhost.cmd('AUTHENTICATE ""') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot authenticate to Tor" if c != "250 OK\n" }
  localhost.cmd('signal NEWNYM') { |c| print c; throw "Cannot switch Tor to new route" if c != "250 OK\n" }
  localhost.close      
  sleep 5

  new_ip = Mechanize.new.get("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com").content
  puts "new IP is #{new_ip}"
end
```